# Bash - Remove last word from grep output

Tags: bash, shell

I am grepping certain folders using grep and awk

```
ls $HOME/.../ | grep ...| gawk -F "-" '{print $3}'
```

This produces 3 folders

rp1 rp2 rp3

rp3 is the latest. I want to remove rp3 from that variable and delete the older ones one by one using rm -rf

Comment: so as final action you need `rm -rf rp1 rp2` or `rm -rf  rp3` ?

Comment: I need to remove rp1 and 2 but I would like to store rp3 for other use

Comment: add sample output of `ls $HOME/.../`

Comment: rp.0.11.8 rp.0.11.9 rp.0.12.0

Comment: [Why you should not parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 1):

No need for `ls`, `find`, `awk`, parsing ls output is not safe.

Supposing there is only one digit, and last is the bigger

```
array=( $HOME/.../*-rp[0-9] )

last_file=${array[-1]}

# remove last element of array
unset array[-1]

echo "${array[@]}"

rm "${array[@]}"
```

If there is more than one digit, and last is the last modified

```
shopt -s extglob

array=( $HOME/.../*-rp+([0-9]) )
last_modified_timestamp=0
for ((i=0;i<${#array[@]};i+=1)); do
    modified_timestamp=$(stat -c %Y "${array[i]}")
    if (( modified_timestamp > last_modified_timestamp )); then
        last_modified_timestamp=$modified_timestamp
        last_index=$i
    fi
done

unset array[$last_index]



# if the keys are important see following
declare -p array
array=( "${array[@]}" )
declare -p array
```

Comment: What happens if there is a `'\n'` or space in the filename? Granted rare unless on a Mac, but it is what makes `find`, an attractive option.

Comment: there is no problem because expansions are done by the shell not parsing ls

Comment: Yes, but what about *word-splitting* in the array assignment?

Comment: `touch 'a b' 'c d'; array=( *' '* ); printf "<%s>\n" "${array[@]}"`

Comment: I stand corrected, well done. I just confirmed. e.g. `touch {one,two}; printf -v foo "%s\n%s\n" three four; touch "$foo"; array=( * ); declare -p array` and output of `declare -a array='([0]="one" [1]="three
four
" [2]="two")'`

Comment: checking manual again `word-splitting` occurs before `filename expansion`